# How to use OPENJSON to concatenate json Array in a column of a table

Tags: arrays, sql-server, open-json

I have a column in SQL table which has a string value denoting a JSON array. I need to concatenate the array for comparison. There are multiple rows of this data and will be using a CURSOR to iterate through a set of values because no example of using using OPENJSON on a column is available

there are solutions for iterating the array in a property `('$.list')` of a JSON but nothing which talks about a direct array.

from:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"id": 1, "val":"j"}, {"id": 2,"val":"o"}, {"id": 3, "val":"h"}, {"id": 4, "val":"h";}, {"id": 5, "val":"n"}] |
| 2 | [{"id": 1, "val":"d"}, {"id": 2,"val":"o"}, {"id": 3, "val":"e"}] |

Result:

| ID | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | **john** |
| 2 | **doe** |

and then proceed with my other iteration logic on the Result table

Comment: The example "JSON" is just a single JSON string literal. Everything between the `"` characters would be invalid JSON, because the standard doesn't support `'` characters to delimit properties and string literals, and so cannot be queried using SQL Server's built-in functions as you're expecting to do.

Comment: updated the JSON value to correct format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you correct the example JSON by switching the `"` and `'` characters around you could get your desired results by way of `string_agg()` and `openjson()`...

```sql
declare @Table table (
  ID int,
  [Value] nvarchar(max)
);

insert @Table (ID, [Value]) values
  (1, N'[{"id": 1, "val":"j"}, {"id": 2,"val":"o"}, {"id": 3, "val":"h"}, {"id": 4, "val":"h"}, {"id": 5, "val":"n"}]'),
  (2, N'[{"id": 1, "val":"d"}, {"id": 2,"val":"o"}, {"id": 3, "val":"e"}]');

select ID, string_agg(J.[val], N'') as [Result]
from @Table
cross apply openjson([Value]) with (
    [val] nvarchar(50)
) J
group by ID;
```

| ID | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | johhn |
| 2 | doe |